# Is it bad programming practice to declare an array type in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, typedef

I have a bunch of arrays of various lengths and I'd like to keep the length close to the array, is it bad programming practice to define something like this?

```c
typedef struct Array {
  long len;
  int* buf;
} Array;
```

Are there any obvious downsides or pitfalls to this?

Comment: On the contrary, keeping related data items together like this is exactly what should be being done.

Comment: No, but you should remember to allocate the memory for the arrays and free when done. You can even consider making functions to allocate and resize the `struct Array`

Comment: A length of type `size_t` will accommodate all array sizes.  `long` may be excessive - or too small.

Comment: Consider recording two numbers — the number of elements allocated, and the number in use.  Clearly, the number in use should never exceed the number allocated, but quite often you'll need to add to an array as you read data, and you don't want to increase the array size by one every time you read a new number.  You should double the number of allocated elements when you need more space.

Comment: There's no problem with that, but that doesn't declare an array type. This declares some array types: `typedef int aint64[64], aint32[32]; ... aint64 foo;`. And yes, some people will hate your guts if you do such a thing ;-)

Comment: What Jonathan said, but also, it is not necessary to *double* the array size each time, just use a fractional factor. And if your array shrinks too, you'd want to use something like `N/(2 * factor)` for the shrinking guide - shrink the array only below this limit when the original array was N items long. That way you will keep amortized constant time insertions and deletiones to the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not necessarily. You will need to pass the length of a buffer around with the pointer to make sure that you don't overrun it. It would be a slight performance hit due to the extra dereference, but that can be a worthwhile tradeoff if always having the length available avoids causing bugs. You would need to make sure that the length gets updated if you resize the buffer, and make sure that the buffer gets freed if you free your struct. Other than that, it makes sense to me, and it's what a lot of other higher-level languages do in their array implementations.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine, a similar structure is commonly used for counted strings, aka vectors, which are not null terminated, hence the need to store their length. I wouldn't bother with this approach if the arrays are only used locally, though.

As it's been noted, it would be better to use an unsigned type such as `size_t` or `uint32_t` for the length.

When dealing with pointers one needs to take the usual precautions to ensure that it always has a valid reference before using or passing around, that allocated memory is freed, etc. Using *valgrind* is highly recommended.